# Me vs. Wikipedia (Lacunary function)?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

I was recently reading this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function
and found atleast the example they are giving must be wrong because I have kind of managed to analytically get an asymptotic result:

The example he gives seems to be a special version of this series:

$$ S(n,x) = e^{n\ln(x)} + e^{n^2\ln(x)} + e^{n^3 ln(x)} + ... $$

However this series also satisfies the partial differential equation:

$$ x \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} - n x^2 \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial x^2} = nS $$

(This was found by me after alot of brute force)

Dividing the PDE by $ x^2 $

$$ \frac{\partial S}{x \partial x} - n \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial x^2} = \frac{nS}{x^2} $$

Taking limit $ x $ tends to infinity:

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\partial S}{x \partial x} -\frac{nS}{x^2} = n \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial x^2}  $$

Now, we have options depending on assuming $ \lim_{x \to \infty} S=\infty $ or $ \lim_{x \to \infty} S'=\infty $

With alot of guesswork we get (the other options when solved the assumption is not justified):

$$ -\frac{nS}{x^2} = n \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial x^2}  $$

We take the solution:

$$ S \sim C \sqrt(x) \sin (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \log(x)) $$

P.S: In general I find it hard to believe there can exist series which cannot be analytically continued.

### Questions

Have I done something wrong? Is wikipedia wrong? Is this a known method of converting a function into a PDE and then taking limits to guess the asymptotic relationship known?

Comment: I think he means in this particular case.

Comment: @LeeMosher I wasn't sure because at the same time I find it difficult to find a flaw in their argument ... So I'm very confused who is wrong over here ...

Comment: So you seem to deny the very existence of lacunary functions? That would be quite a bold claim to make. Now, what's the behavior of your series in the close vicinity of 0? Kind of $S(x)\approx x$, apparently. And what about your analytical solution?

Comment: @IvanNeretin  ... If you follow my method taking limit $x$ to $0$ ... We get $S \sim x $

Comment: Wait, didn't you just say that $S \sim C x^{(1 - \sqrt{5})/2}$?

Comment: I did (however intially I solved the differential equation wrong) and secondly that was only for the limit $ x \to \infty $

Comment: Are you sure that your derivation of the PDE is correct? I plugged the series directly and it looks like the LHS doesn't match the RHS.

Comment: @pregunton ... Thank you ... I will be editing the entire post ....